# RDP hangs when connecting to a machine in another subnet

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

I'm having problems connecting trough RDP to a machine in another subnet

Both networks are connected trough a series of FortiGate routers

The symptoms are that when I click connect the window where I need to type my user and password is stuck in the background and is not interactable . If you wait 10-15 min the windows appears as normal and you can type in it ( I use windows 11 but I dont think its exclusive)

I know I am being vague about details but I wanted to ask what should I be checking to see why the process is so slow.
RDP seems to be the only thing affected as ping works fine and not much latency for example

Comment: When you suspect networking being the issue, **what network traffic do you see** on the machine that's stuck? Does [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) show it trying to talk to its AD domain controller, or something else? Is it trying to use Kerberos, is it trying to fetch a CRL from your internal CA, is it making DNS queries?